# Find Max Value of Unknown Function in Interval

Tags: javascript, algorithm, function, optimization, max

Given a continuous but unknown function `f(x)`, how can I find the maximum value it reaches in a closed interval by calling `f(x)` as few times as possible?

The function is unknown so I can't take the derivative explicitly. The only way to check values is by calling it. `f(x)` in the given interval will only have one critical point, but max value can be at the endpoints.

I don't need super high precision. Let's say if the method exceeds a certain number of iterations, it will stop and return the current largest value.

Comment: You actually *can* take the derivative, since you can computationally calculate (estimate) the derivative.

Comment: Can function have several local extrema or it is unimodal?

Comment: @SergeyMell Only one local extrema

Comment: Given "only one local extrema", assuming that extrema is a local max, then a simple binary search should suffice. If it is rather a local min, then make sure to include the interval endpoints in your search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a divide-and conquer process.

The endpoints (a, f(a)) and (b, f(b)) divide the y-axis into three regions, with horizontal borders at f(a) and f(b).   w.l.o.g. I'll restrict the discussion to the first quadrant, assuming f(b) > f(a)

```
     |
     |
f(b)-+-------------------------*-----------
     |
     |
     |
     |
f(a)-+-*-----------------------------------
     |
     |
     +-a-------r--------s------b-----
```

Take two other values, 'r' and 's' such that `a < r < s < b`.  Since there is no more than one inflection point, there are some restrictions on the various possibilities for f(r) and f(s) ordered with the endpoints.

If both are less than f(b), then the maximum point must be to the right of `s`, the interval [s, b].

If f(r) is high, then so is f(s).
f(r) > f(s) > f(b) implies that the max is in the interval [a, s]
f(s) > f(r) > f(b) implies that the max is in the interval [r, b]

The remaining case is f(a) < f(r) < f(b) and f(s) > f(b).  Again, we get that the max must be to the right of f(r), the second point in the previous case, interval [r, b].

With this determination made, iterate on the remaining interval.  For [a, s] or [r, b], we already have one point in the interval; choose one more in the larger side (if the two are equal size, choose either); for [s, b], we need two more points.

The simplistic way to choose points is to simply bisect or trisect the interval in question.  If you want to try something fancier, use your history of points to approximate the function (e.g. spline fit) and choose points so as to converge more quickly.

Does that get you going?

Comment: Thanks! I implemented the trisection method with some modifications and it works pretty well.